# Identical objects in list

Tags: python, list, append

**is it possible to detect identical objects as different variables, say object1=(1,2,3) and object2=**(1,2,3).

```
list = []
```

If i now put object 1 in the list together with object 2 the list becomes:

```
list.append(object1)
list.append(object1)
print(list)
list = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

How can i let python decide whether or not the first element in the list is object1?
This is something i have to do for my school project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. 
You can do this with the `is` function.

```
Block1 is Block2
list[0] is list[1]
```

response: False

Answer (score 1):

The computer does only what you tell it to do. So if you append something twice, it will listen. If you want it to do it under a condition, you need to use an if statement and compare the values within the list to the value you are trying to add. To make this easier, I would put this in a function so you can call this logic easily

In your case, I'm assuming you only want to add the object if it doesn't exist:

```
list = []
def addToList(elem):
    global list # allows the function to modify this variable that would be normally out of scope
    if elem not in list:
        list.append(elem)

object1 = [1,2,3]
addToList(object1)
addToList(object1)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could cast to set then back to list:

```
my_list = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
print(list(set(my_list)))
# [(1, 2, 3)]
```

or you could check first if your object is already in the list:

```
if object1 not in my_list:
    my_list.append(object1)
```